# CodeActivity integration with TFS2015

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've included custom code activities in TFS2012 and below.

In the "new world" changes in TFS2015, (non-work-flow driven)......I cannot figure out how to add a custom activity.

[image]

Now do I integrate the below into a TFS 2015 build?

```
using System.Activities;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;

namespace MyCompany.TFS.CodeCoverageLibrary
{
    [BuildExtension(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
    public sealed class SimpleCodeActivity : CodeActivity<bool>
    {
        protected override bool Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            context.TrackBuildMessage(string.Format("ActivityInstanceId='{0}', WorkflowInstanceId='{1}'", context.ActivityInstanceId, context.WorkflowInstanceId));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The new build system is a complete, ground-up rewrite. XAML build activities won't work in the new build system, although they will continue to work in the XAML build system.

The new task system is based on JSON descriptor files with activities written as PowerShell (for Windows) or Node JS (for cross-platform). You can see examples of the task library on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks

Comment: Ok, so to use my (now antiquated) SimpleCodeActivity, I need to stick with XAML build definitions.  Or convert (all of) my custom-code to the new world. Correct?

Comment: @granadaCoder Correct.